# How do I change the color of the background of a clipped path

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I want to wrap my div with a clipped path in navy.

Here is my HTML and CSS

```css
.clipboard {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-image: url(https://assets.nationbuilder.com/wave/pages/9/attachments/original/1552266959/blueGradientBG.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.topArea {
  clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 900px 0px, 900px 600px, 450px 750px, 0px 600px);
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navywrapper {
  width: 900px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: navy
}
```

```html
<div class="navywrapper">
  <div class="clipboard topArea">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x85" class="eventImgInfo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x85" class="eventImgInfo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x85" class="eventImgInfo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x85" class="eventImgInfo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x85" class="eventImgInfo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x85" class="eventImgInfo">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how I want it to look
[image]

Comment: can you be more clear on your need? probably show us a mockup